# Can printf, scnaf,,(I/O functions in stdio.h) be called API?

Tags: operating-system

I'm learning Operating System on Windows, Linux(Ubuntu).
According to my text book(OS concepts 10th edition), on a view point of OS, API is kind of set of functions to interact with Kernel(Like system call)... SO my Question is this..

1. Is stdio.h can be called API??
2. library like stdio.h can be used across the
   platform(Ubuntu,Windows..). Is there common API, like
   stdio.h, which can be used across the platform??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know that the C language is just a convention. When a developer like you or anyone implements a compiler, they write that compiler for a specific OS. This means that stdio.h is basically a set of functions which are  going to be compiled specifically for an OS and it will work only on that OS except if another OS implements the same function in the same manner (with the same system call). Basically, everything which requires a system call is specific to one OS, everything else is going to be cross platform because it relies only on the underlying processor.

In itself an operating system can be described as a  program which is written in C/C++ but with dependency on the processor the OS will run on. When you are writing an OS, you can't use any functions which normally require system calls because it is up to you to implement the system calls. What it means is that you are left with the basic language like pointers, functions, structs, etc.

I wouldn't call stdio.h an API because an API is more like functions that you can call from a language like C/C++ that will call in the kernel directly. For example, on Windows you have the CreateWindowExW() function that you can use from C++ to create a window. This function responds better to the definition of an API while printf() isn't really an API but more like a high level function which is compiled to an API call.

In the end, the compiler you use will compile a text file like a .cpp or .c to an executable in a certain conventional format. It is up to you to interpret that conventional format when you bootstrap the computer (if you are writing an OS). For example, the Linux kernel is compiled to a .elf file which is a conventional file format. Then the bootstrap code like GRUB will interpret that file format to be able to jump to the entry point of the kernel. The Linux kernel is a statically linked C program which uses only the basic C language like pointers etc.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Ok then,,,, you meant that printf function itself is like shell(like driver function which call workhorse function) covering the real system call function(and this function is likely to be called api on your definition).           Is it right??????.

Comment: Yes basically, printf is implemented as a high level function which calls the Linux/Windows API function which does the actual printing.

Comment: And one more, may I?

Comment: Sure. Go ahead.

Comment: Umm Sorry, I will ask it later, I need to look at my study file first.

Comment: It a is a compressed .elf file compressed with gzip or something similar.

Comment: Oh thank you, can I ask you about Linux kernel later ? I think you are the answerer who have given good answer to me.....

Comment: What I said is not completely true. Grub won't jump to the entry point of the kernel.

Comment: Feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: You should ask a new question if you think it is fit for the site. Also see cs.stackexchange.com to ask general questions about operating-systems. This stackexchange is more fit for your kind of questions.

Comment: Ok, One Question that I want to ask to you. Currently I am studying signal in Ubuntu. Here is my Question

Comment: 1. Signal is the Linux version interrupt is that right??

Comment: 2. then, I know system call (such as write) is kind of interrupt, which in Linux, the signal, then,  Among the list of signal below. What signal is actually called when system call (write, read, fork,...) made??

Comment: SIGHUP, SIGINT, SIGQUIT, SIGILL, SIGTRAP, SIGABRT, SIGBUS ...

Comment: I can't answer here since it is too wide a subject. You should ask a new question on cs.stackexchange.com instead. General questions about how operating-systems work is welcome there. Since it is a stackexchange for computer science, operating-system questions should be welcome if well formulated and based on the theory of operating-systems.